PowerShell Exchange Commands Not Working in Docker on Linux for Exchange On-Premises 2007
I am currently developing a REST API that needs to interact with an on-premises Microsoft Exchange server (Exchange 2007, not Office 365) through PowerShell commands. In my development environment (Windows), everything works perfectly. The API uses the New-PSSession cmdlet to establish a remote session to the Exchange server and runs commands such as Get-Mailbox and Enable-Mailbox.
Here is a snippet of my PowerShell code:
# Establish Exchange session
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://$exchangeServer/PowerShell/" -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $credential

# Import the session
Import-PSSession $session -DisableNameChecking

# Test connection
try {
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 1
    Write-Output "Successful connection to Exchange."
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Could not connect to Exchange: $_"
    Remove-PSSession $session
    exit
}

# Add mailbox or permissions
try {
    Enable-Mailbox -Identity $usuario -Alias $alias
    Write-Output "Mailbox created for user $usuario."
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Failed to grant permissions: $_"
}

# Disconnect from Exchange
Remove-PSSession $session

The issue arises when I try to containerize this API in a Docker image running on Linux. I install pwsh (PowerShell Core) in the Dockerfile and attempt to install the necessary Exchange modules. However, when running the container in production, none of the Exchange commands work.
I understand that Exchange cmdlets like New-PSSession and Get-Mailbox might not be compatible with Linux-based PowerShell, but I can't find a clear solution or workaround. Here's what I need help with:
Is it possible to run PowerShell Exchange commands from a Linux-based Docker container for an on-premises Exchange server (Exchange 2007)?
If not, are there any alternatives to running these commands remotely from within a Docker container? Perhaps a way to configure the container or utilize Windows-based containers?
Is there a way to troubleshoot why these Exchange commands fail on Linux?
I am looking for any suggestions, documentation, or workarounds that would allow me to run this code within a Docker container.
Thanks in advance!
I’ve installed pwsh (PowerShell Core) in a Linux-based Docker container and attempted to install the Exchange modules, but the commands don’t work. I also tried using Windows-based containers, but couldn't get them to work properly either.
I expected the PowerShell Exchange commands to execute within the Docker container, either through Linux or Windows-based images, to interact with my on-premises Exchange server

The documentation implies this is a Windows only module.
